# Inserting iframe from chrome extension doesn't work on some sites

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a content script from a chrome extension inserting an iframe into a website like so.

```
const mainiframe = document.createElement('iframe')
mainiframe.setAttribute("id", "ext_frame");
mainiframe.style.border = "none"
mainiframe.style.display = "block"
mainiframe.style.position = "fixed"
mainiframe.style.height = "100%";
mainiframe.style.width = "100%";
mainiframe.style.top = "0";
mainiframe.style.left = "0";
mainiframe.style.bottom = "0"
mainiframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("index.html")
document.body.appendChild(mainiframe)
```

And index.html just has some boilerplate like.

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

(it doesn't seem to matter whats in index.html). index.html is mentioned in web_acccessible_resources in the manifest.json as required.

This works great on *most* websites. Here it is working fine on [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

[image: Here it is working fine on www.google.com]
[image: The visual result]

However, on some websites, the iframe insertion simply doesn't work. No matter what is done. Running the same code on [www.homedepot.com](http://www.homedepot.com) for example, leads to no changes in the DOM. Is there something I should be doing in the manifest to make sure it can be inserted on any site?

Comment: It's either a bug in Chrome or the page simply deletes the iframe. You can make a `div`, attach a [shadow root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) in `closed` mode, and make the iframe there so the page won't be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks! A ShadowRoot fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [wOxxOm's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540805/inserting-iframe-from-chrome-extension-doesnt-work-on-some-sites?noredirect=1#comment119384175_67540805) comment, sticking the iframe in a closed shadow root seems to fix the problem! For anyone else looking for a solution instead of just a:

```
document.body.appendChild(mainiframe)
```

I did a,

```
const maindiv = document.createElement('div')
let shadowParent = maindiv.attachShadow({mode:'closed'})
shadowParent.appendChild(mainiframe)
document.body.appendChild(maindiv)
```

And that worked great! In this particular case the problem was the website forcibly removing iframes. I think [noninertialframe's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67542364/3333201) answer may have worked too, but it would require me to restructure my internal app.

Answer (score 1):

My extension also inserts an iframe, but I wrap my iframe inside a span and a div. Does inserting a span or div work on those websites?

Also, my manifest.json is as follows.

```
{
    "name": "PageNow",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-....'; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["./content_static/static/js/main.js", "/content_static/static/js/1.chunk.js"],
            "css": ["./content_static/static/css/main.css"],
            "match_about_blank": true
        }
    ],
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["http://localhost:4200/*"]
    }
}
```

I used React for the content script, and the part that inserts an element that contains iframe is as follows.

```
const elemId = "extension-root";

const element = document.getElementById(elemId);
if (element) {
    alert("Already loaded");
} else {
    const extElement = document.createElement("span");
    extElement.id = elemId;
    document.body.appendChild(extElement);
    
    ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
        extElement
    );
}
```

The iframe is inside the div which is inside the span 'extension-root'.

Comment: <div's> and <span's> do work. It just doesn't like the iframe.src = <another html file>. It seems you don't do that? You have a span, and the react app then inserts an iframe in there? 

I might try that and report back! Thank you.